# Laravel 5.5 user event listener not working

Tags: laravel, events, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have set up an event that should run whenever a user registers successfully. The event runs but the listener handler is never triggered.

Any one know what I've done wrong here? I'm using Laravel 5.5 on a local development server (wamp).

It's not even getting to the listener's `handle()` function, I put a dump in there to test.

Below is my code:

Event:

```
class UserRegisteredEmail extends Event {
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    public $password;

    public function __construct($user, $password)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Event Listener:

```
 class UserRegisteredEmailListener {

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function handle(UserRegisteredEmail $event)
    {
        Notification::send($event->user, new NewAccountEmail($event->password));
    }
}
```

EventServiceProvider:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\Event' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
            'App\Listeners\UserRegisteredEmailListener'
        ],
    ];


    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        //
    }
}
```

`UserService` where the event is dispatched:

```
    DB::transaction(function () use ($user, $password, $role, $sendEmail) {
                    $this->userMeta->firstOrCreate([
                        'user_id' => $user->id
                    ]);

                if ($sendEmail) {
                    event(new UserRegisteredEmail($user, $password));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your real `EventServiceProvider` it isn't correct, it should be something more like:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserRegisteredEmail' => [
        'App\Listeners\UserRegisteredEmailListener'
    ],
];
```

A separate, but semi-related note, you might want to rename some of your classes to be more generic. This helps in the future if you want to add any additional events/listeners. Maybe `App\Events\UserRegisteredEmail` could change to `App\Events\UserWasCreated` and `App\Listeners\UserRegisteredEmailListener` could change to `App\Listeners\SendUserWelcomeEmail`

Comment: This seems to have worked! Can you explain why it didn't work with my original array in the $listen property? I'll accept as soon as it lets me. Thanks

Comment: Your `UserRegisteredEmail` class was never set as an event in the provider, so Laravel was unaware that it had to do anything with your event when it was called. For each array item in `$listen` you'll have to specify the event as a new key, then the value would be an array of listeners. In my answer, we are specifying that the `UserRegisteredEmail` is the event Laravel will look for and the listeners it executes will just be `UserRegisteredEmailListener`

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register it:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserRegisteredEmail' => [
        'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        'App\Listeners\UserRegisteredEmailListener'
    ],
];
```

> The listen property contains an array of all events (keys) and their listeners (values). Of course, you may add as many events to this array as your application requires.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/events#registering-events-and-listeners